# OnClick action after actual action in h:commandButton

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I have a marketplace application, and in the payment page, there's a `h:form` with some validations on the fields. I have a `h:commandButton` to submit the form and perform an action in the back-end.

The code is this:

```
<div class="form-actions">
<h:commandButton onclick="setTimeout($('#adios').modal('show'),50)" 
value="Pay!" action="#{basketManager.pay(accountManager.currentAccount.username)}"
class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"/> 
</div>
```

The `modal` just displays a message. But I want this action to be performed after the `h:form` validations are correctly met, or even better, after the `action` inside the `h:commandButton` (which by the way is not working, it only works if I remove the `onClick`)

Any ideas?

EDIT: Thanks to @SRy for his advice, but there's still problems. This is my code now:

```
<div class="form-actions">
<p:commandButton oncomplete="$('#adios').modal('show')" 
value="Pay!" action="#{basketManager.pay(accountManager.currentAccount.username)}"
styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: Then use primefaces `<p:commandButton>` which has `onComplete` event , cause in this case as soon as you click the button , javascript function gets executed before to your actual action method.

Comment: @SRy I did apply the change, but the modal still displays without the action being executed... I edited the question.

Comment: Are you sure? Cause in `<p:commandButton/>`if you don't specify `ajax=false`, i will execute with ajax behavior. So, debug or try with `ajax=false` and you can try `onsuccess`

Comment: I agree with SRy. The action should be executed if no validation errors occur. If it just in case of failed validation that `modal`shows without action performed try `oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) $('#adios').modal('show')"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use Primefaces commandbutton `p:commandButton` for easy execution or you can do somthing like this

```
 <h:commandButton 
    value="Pay!" action="#{basketManager.pay(accountManager.currentAccount.username)}"
    class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
     <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form" onevent=showdlg();/>
   </h:commandButton>
```

JavaScript

```
function showdlg(data){
       if(data.status=='success'){
          setTimeout($('#adios').modal('show'),50);
          }
      }
```